# Add native dll file to intelliJ

Tags: java, dll, intellij-idea, dllimport

So I have this dll I need to implement in my java project in intelliJ
I already tried something which is in the dependecies tab.
I also got the error in the console:

```
Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

BTW, I have intel processor.

Comment: Fixed it with using the 32bits JDK, and the right path to my java -Djava.library.path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're running the 64 bit version of IntelliJ and/or the JDK and your library was compiled for 32 bit.

You either need to get a new version of the library that is 64 bit or contact Jetbrains to see if there is a 32 bit version of IntelliJ on Windows.

And a side note - "AMD 64" is a 64 bit variation on x86 chips.  The 32 bit chips were originally done by Intel.  Both Intel and AMD came out with 64 bit chips at about the same time.  But Intel made their 64 bit chip incompatible with the 32 bit chips.  AMD made them compatible.  That is why you don't hear anything about [Itanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) chips anymore.  Intel chips now use the AMD64 architecture which is what the error is referring to.

Comment: Fixed it with using the 32bits JDK, and the right path to my java -Djava.library.path... But thanks anyway !!